# Why my if/else statement doesn't work? (shell)

Tags: shell

I have problem with this shell script:

```
current_time=$(date +"%T"); 
current_day_of_week="$(date +'%u')"; 
if [[ current_day_of_week == 1 ]]; 
then echo "Setting max time to 03:00:00" && max_time="03:00:00"; 
else echo "Setting max time to 01:30:00" && max_time="01:30:00"; fi;
```

I want to set variable `max_time` to `03:00:00` when it's monday, but the code doesn't work :(

Answer (score 1):

The string "current_day_of_week" is not the same as the string "1".  If you want to compare the value of the variable, you need to dereference it.  Replace

```
if [[ current_day_of_week == 1 ]];
```

with

```
if [ "$current_day_of_week" = 1 ];
```

Since you're not getting a syntax error, we can assume you are using a `shell` that supports the `[[` syntax (you should probably change the tag !) so you can use:

```
if [[ $current_day_of_week == 1 ]];
```

Note that although quoting variables is not strictly necessary inside the `[[` construct, it is a good idea to use quotes anyway:

```
if [[ "$current_day_of_week" == 1 ]];
```